# Debug running Tizen Web Application...?

Tags: web-applications, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Tizen Studio has a way to run a Web App in debug mode, which is very handy, but as soon as application is closed, the console gets disconnected as well.

I wonder if it is possible to remotely connect to already running application and debug it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possible to do it on SmartTVs. To obtain all the data from the beginning of the life cycle of the application, a possible workaround is to press F5 to force the reload of the remote application (once the application is debugging and you have the chromium ready on your PC)

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is possible if the application was started in debug mode and you know the debug port. Samsung is just using Chrome DevTools. The Chrome DevTools can connect to a remote debugging session provided you know the IP and port to connect to.

Drop me a comment if you'd like more details. All the details I have are on another machine but the comment will remind me to get them for you.